# Reactjs components error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am completely new to React and I need to make an infinite scroll effect by including some divs from another component. I have found an infinite scroll library online and I am using it here in the index.js file. I have created my divs in Home.js but I am getting some errors like:-
**Error: Mandatory prop "refreshFunction" missing.** and **TypeError: this.props.next is not a function**. Can someone help me out please. I think even though I am exporting Home.js and then importing it in index.js but it is still not able to invoke the methods. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to correct it? I have added the code below.

**index.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import { Home } from "./components/Home";

class App extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
            pullDownToRefresh
            pullDownToRefreshContent={
                <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8595; Pull down to refresh</h3>
            }
            releaseToRefreshContent={
                <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8593; Release to refresh</h3>
            }
            refreshFunction={this.refresh}
            next={this.generateDivs}
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
            endMessage={
                <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
                </p>
            }>

            <Home/>

        </InfiniteScroll>
    );

}
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**Home.js**

```jsx
import React from "react";

const style = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontSize: 40,
    border: '2px solid red',
    margin: ' 0 auto 10px auto',
    textAlign: 'center'
}

const divs = [
    <div key={1} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 1</div>,
    <div key={2} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 2</div>,
    <div key={3} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 3</div>,
    <div key={4} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 4</div>,
    <div key={5} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 5</div>,
    <div key={6} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 6</div>,
    <div key={7} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 7</div>,
    <div key={8} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>Div no 8</div>,
];


export class Home extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            divs: divs
        };
        this.generateDivs = this.generateDivs.bind(this);
        this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
    }

    generateDivs() {
        let moreDivs = [];
        let count = this.state.divs.length;
        console.log(count);
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            moreDivs.push(
                <div key={'div' + count++} style={{ height: 200, ...style }}>
                    Div no {count}
                </div>
            );
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ divs: this.state.divs.concat(moreDivs) });
        }, 500);
    }

    refresh() {
        this.setState({ divs: [] });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ divs });
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {this.state.divs}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `generateDivs` and `refresh` in `App` not `Home`.

Comment: `refreshFunction={this.refresh}` and `next={this.generateDivs}` are actually supplying the `undefined`.